# htaccess is not returning required value

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My htaccess looks like following

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?module=modelname&action=pagename&reff=$1
```

I have used index.php as a controller to render the view using the parameter module and action,

I want to rewrite the following url
http://example.com/username/splash

and wanted to get username but when I print $_GET['reff'] it prints index.php

Can anyone please suggest whats wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You're seeing `$_GET['reff']=index.php` because your rewrite rule is running twice**. First on `/username/splash` URI and then 2nd time on `/index.php` URI. It is due to the fact that your URI pattern `^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$` matches both URIs.

To prevent this unwanted behavior you need to have your rule like this:

```
# if request is not for a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# if request is not for a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?module=modelname&action=pagename&reff=$1 [L,QSA]
```